# Optimize Mysql Query (rawdata to processed table)

Tags: mysql, database

Hi everyone so my question is this, So I have a file that reads in roughly 3000 rows of data by the local infile command. After which there is a trigger on the table that's inserted into that copies three columns from from the updated table and two columns from a table that exist in the database already(if this is unclear to what I mean the structures are coming). From there only combinations that have unique glNumbers will be entered into the processed table. This takes over a minute and half normally. I find this pretty long, I was wondering if this is normal for what I'm doing(can't believe that's true) or is there a way to optimize the queries so it goes faster?

Tables that are inserted to are labeled the first three letters of each month. Here is the default structure.

**RawData Structure**

```
| idjan | glNumber  | journel  | invoiceNumber  | date  | JT  | debit  | credit | descriptionDetail  | totalDebit  | totalCredit |
```

(sorry) for the poor format there isn't a really good way to do this it seems)

**After Insert Trigger Query**

```
delete from processedjan;
insert into processedjan(glNumber,debit,credit,bucket1,bucket2)
select  a.glNumber, a.totalDebit, a.totalCredit, b.bucket1, b.bucket2
from jan a inner join bucketinformation b on a.glNumber = b.glNumber
group by glNumber;
```

**Processed Datatable Structure**

| glNumber | bucket1| bucket2| credit | debit |

Also I guess it helps to know the bucket 1 and bucket 2 come from another table where its matched against the glNumber. That table is roughly 800 rows with three columns for the glNumber and the two buckets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While [postgresql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtrigger.html) has statement level triggers, mysql only has row level triggers. From the [mysql reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/triggers.html):

> A trigger is defined to activate when a statement inserts, updates, or
>   deletes rows in the associated table. These row operations are trigger
>   events. For example, rows can be inserted by INSERT or LOAD DATA
>   statements, and an insert trigger activates for each inserted row.

So while you are managing to load 3000 rows in one operation, unfortunately 3000 more queries are executed by the triggers. But the complex nature of your transaction sounds like you might actually be performing 2-3 queries per row. That's the real reason for the slow down.

You can speed things up by disabling the trigger and carrying out a INSERT .. SELECT after the load data in file. You can automate it with a small script.

Comment: Oh I see. I didn't know that. I'll check it out after lunch and I'll let you know.

Comment: you were right. Sorry it took so long to answer back i think I crazy deleted something in my application and it made broke so had to fix that. Thanks for the help. I wish the MySQL documentation was a bit better.